# How to get the following situation solved in odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I am trying to print a many2many field value in qweb pdf report

Following is the code

purchase_quotation.py

```
class purchase_quotation(osv.Model):

    _name="purchase.quotation"
    _rec_name='vno'
    _columns={
        'name':fields.many2one('res.users','Name', readonly=True),
        'date':fields.date('Order Date', required=True),
        'vno':fields.char('Voucher No',size=40,readonly=1),
        'branch':fields.selection([
    ('blockA', 'Block A'),
        ('blockB', 'Block B'),
        ('admin', 'Admin'),

        ], 'Branch/Office', readonly= False, select=True, required=True),
        'user_manager_id':fields.many2one('res.users','Manager'),
        'approve_by':fields.char('Approved By'),
        'order_line': fields.one2many('product.text', 'pro_ref', 'Order Lines',required=True),
    }
```

purchase_order.py

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "purchase.order"
    _columns = {
            'vno_ref':fields.many2many('purchase.quotation', 'voch_ref' , string='Ref.Voucher No'),
            'spo':fields.many2one('res.users','Submit To', domain = [('is_approver','=',True)],),

    }
```

code in qweb pdf report

```
<div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
            <strong>Order Date:</strong>
            <p t-field="o.date_order" t-field-options='{"widget": "date"}'/>
            <strong>Ref Voucher No:</strong>
            <p t-field="o.vno_ref"/>
</div>
```

How can i display the values of many2many fields in the qweb pdf report. Anyone having an idea on this?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the sale order report u will find the best solution for you

I sale order line having the tax_id which is part of many2many field.

You can access that field using below way

```
<tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="l">
     <td>
         <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, l.tax_id))"/>
     </td>
</tr>
```

same way you can implement that field on your own way for your Qweb View report rendering and then after check to print your PDF report

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: DaSadiya Chaitanya, First of all thank you very much, can you just please tell me whether many2many declaration in purchase.order in the above code is correct? As i am slightly confused

Comment: i do not know what comes after a relation table in many2many field(is it a field)?

Comment: <tr t-foreach="o" t-as="l">
     <td>
         <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, l.vno_ref))"/>
     </td>
</tr>

Comment: you can do above way

Comment: DasaDiya Chaitanya- can you help me on this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938923/how-to-achieve-the-following-scenario-in-odoo ?

Comment: I will check for give me some time for checking update with u soon

Comment: Ok DasaDiya Chaitanya

Comment: Can i ask you one more thing ? how can we add dynamic rows depending on the number of records in many2many field? Suppose there are 5 items, now the above code will print A,B,C,D,E in the same line, how to print in different lines , one down the other ?

Comment: Just iterate the loop using t-foreach via list

Comment: Thank you very much Chaitanya..!!

Comment: Welcome bro u r from which state ..??

Comment: From Karnataka bro.. how about you ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938923/how-to-achieve-the-following-scenario-in-odoo. please suggest any solution on this bro , if you are free

Comment: you are from which place brother ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103039/discussion-between-shravya-shetty-and-dasadiya-chaitanya).